# CUDA fails to launch while running seq2seq model

Tags: matlab, deep-learning

When I train the sequence to sequence model. This error occurred--

Warning: An unexpected error occurred during CUDA execution. The CUDA error was:
CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED

After that, I can't use the GPU to run any function like gpuArray(). There is no problem when I train any image classification model after restarting the Matlab or before running this model.

model: #sample 1250 in each segment

```
layers = [ ...
    sequenceInputLayer(40)
    bilstmLayer(200,'OutputMode','sequence')
    dropoutLayer(0.5)
    bilstmLayer(150,"OutputMode","sequence")
    dropoutLayer(0.5)
    bilstmLayer(100,"OutputMode","sequence")
    dropoutLayer(0.5)
    fullyConnectedLayer(4)
    softmaxLayer
    classificationLayer];
  
options = trainingOptions('adam', ...
    'MaxEpochs',20, ...
    'MiniBatchSize',32, ...
    'InitialLearnRate',0.01, ...
    'LearnRateDropPeriod',5, ...
    'LearnRateSchedule','piecewise', ...
    'ValidationData',{fsstValidationData(:,1),labelValidationData},...
    'ValidationFrequency',5,...
    "ValidationPatience",inf,...
    'GradientThreshold',1, ...
    'Plots','training-progress',...
    'shuffle','every-epoch',...
    'Verbose',0,...
    'DispatchInBackground',true);
```

GPU: RTX 2060 super 8 GB;
MATLAB: 2020a

Comment: Don't you have any other logs than `CUDA_ERROR_LAUNCH_FAILED`? If so please include them

Comment: Error using trainNetwork (line 170)
Unexpected error calling cuDNN: CUDNN_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED.